# Redirect to login from .NET Core auth middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I have an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC app, and I'm using auth middleware to authenticate and ensure that an access token (JWT) resides in the cookies.

Working to make sure that when an action with an `[Authorize]` attribute, and the token (authentication) and a specific cookie (authorization) don't exist, the user is redirected to a login page to re-authenticate.

How would I go about re-directing the user to the /login page given the below code?

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseAuth(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
    {
        if (ctx.Request.Headers.ContainsKey(AuthorizationHeader))
        {
            ctx.Request.Headers.Remove(AuthorizationHeader);
        }

        if (ctx.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey(AccessTokenCookieName))
        {
            var authenticateResult = await ctx.AuthenticateAsync(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            if (authenticateResult.Succeeded && authenticateResult.Principal is not null)
            {
                ctx.User = authenticateResult.Principal;
            }

            var path = ctx.Request.Path;
        }
        else
        {
            // REDIRECT TO LOGIN?
        }

        await next();
    });

    return app;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any insight you can provide.

Comment: Have you tried something like `ctx.Response.Redirect("/login");` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core, you typically manage redirection to a login page when authorization fails by configuring the authentication services and the challenge response in the `Startup.cs` or `Program.cs` file, not directly in the middleware. However, if you want to handle this within a custom middleware, you can do so by checking if the authentication result was unsuccessful and then redirecting the user accordingly. Something like this.

```
var authenticateResult = await ctx.AuthenticateAsync(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

if (authenticateResult.Succeeded && authenticateResult.Principal is not null)
{
   ctx.User = authenticateResult.Principal;
   await next();
}
else
{
   if (!ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/login"))
   {
     ctx.Response.Redirect($"/login?ReturnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(ctx.Request.Path + ctx.Request.QueryString)}");
   }
   else
   {
     await next(); 
     delegate/middleware in the pipeline
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  This seems to be working as intended - more testing to do.  If you had a link to documentation around the Program/Startup way of accomplishing this, I would consume it and reconsider my approach.  Thanks again!

Comment: @coach_rob check out this. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-8.0